# Cloud9 ide and running unit tests for a Django project

Tags: django, unit-testing, cloud9-ide

Can anyone tell me how I can run unit tests on a Python/Django project when using Cloud9 IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Cloud9 supports Python 2.6.6 so you won't have unittest testing framework available.

unittest2 is a back port for Python 2.4+, and you can use that in Cloud9. See docs at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2

Simply from the Terminal type 'easy_install unittest2'

Make sure when you write a test, use the unittest2 module

```
import unittest2

class MyTest(unittest2.TestCase):

#tests in here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest2.main()
```

Hope that helps!